# Is it like a poem? It doesn't even rhyme!

Tags: word, wordplay

- Conceivably one in ten kittens make a sound.
- It was his choice to decline a military mission.
- The point of the Easter activity is making my heart race.
- Deliver to my friends and me a short, liqueur-soaked, flourless cake-like pastry, you ancient, lethargic creature!
- It's exhilarating to live like an ancient Native American!
- The specimen is an overhead shade from the sun.

Each bullet represents one word, and together they indicate the answer word.

These are [double definition clues](http://bestforpuzzles.com/cryptic-crossword-tutorial/double-definitions.html), but there is word play involved. For instance:

> A kid in the ocean can float => boy an' sea / buoyancy

Comment: Not getting too far on these, though I'm pretty novice to cryptic clues.  Just to clarify, these clues do follow the format of cryptic crosswords?

Comment: @TwoBitOperation I'm also very new to cryptic clues, and these are *not* standard; see new hint. Any suggestions for a different/additional tag for this? Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: Honestly, I think wordplay covers it just fine. Cryptic clues was a little misleading at first

Comment: (Technically, these are more like homophone clues without indicators, with the exception of "overheard" in the last clue. Double definitions describe two different meanings of the same word, or at least of words that are written the same. Of course, if all your clues follow the same pattern, there may be no need for an explicit indicator, but don't label them as crytic clues then)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I think I get the idea:

Conceivably one in ten kittens make a sound.

> Perchance / purr chance

It was his choice to decline a military mission

> Option / Ops. shun

The point of the Easter activity is making my heart race.

> Exciting / eggs hiding

Deliver to my friends and me a short, liqueur-soaked, flourless cake-like pastry, you ancient, lethargic creature!

> Tortoise / torte us!

It's exhilarating to live like an ancient Native American!

> Intense / in tents

The specimen is an overhead shade from the sun.

> Canopy / can o' pee  (Ew)

FINAL ANSWER:

> POETIC

Comment: Maybe Rot13(rtt fvtugvat)? Either way, 'sall good, man!

Comment: Hm. I could solve only one, and not even correctly. (I thought that someone of Incan descent might be incandescent.)